# In React componentDidUpdate, can props and state change at the same time?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

In a react component, normally you should not mutate props inside it. Also, the parent can only change the props, not the state directly. Based on these two facts, is it correct to assume that in any call of componentDidUpdate e.g.,

componentDidUpdate(prevProps: Readonly>, prevState: Readonly)

this.props could be different from prevProps, OR this.state could be different from prevState, but both situation cannot occur at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous):

> React may batch multiple setState() calls into a single update for
>   performance.

So my best guess based on that is that for performance reasons React may group together props and state updates to perform only one update instead of two. So to answer your question:

> this.props could be different from prevProps, OR this.state could be
>   different from prevState, but both situations cannot occur at the same
>   time?

**I think** it may actually happen like previously said - for performance reasons.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but sometimes initial state depends on props, so in such a case, how do we know whether to re-initialize state in response to the change in props, or to go ahead and use the new state as is?

Comment: _"how do we know whether to re-initialize state in response to the change in props"_? by checking what is the new value of props and state?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, indeed the following code sometimes outputs `true` (depending on the context).

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    const bothChanged = (prevProps !== this.props) && (prevState !== this.state);
    console.log(bothChanged);  // "true" (sometimes)
}
```